# sequence of functions, limits and integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

For the following two sequences of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, find $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$, and compare $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n$ (if it exists) to $\int_{0}^{1}f$ (if it exists).

(a) $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
          n^2x, \quad  &  0\leq x \leq\frac{1}{2n} \\
          n-n^2x, \quad &\frac{1}{2n}\leq x \leq\frac{1}{n} \\
          0, \quad &\frac{1}{n}\leq x \leq 1 \\
     \end{cases}$

(b) $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
          1, \quad &\text{if} \, x=\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}  \text{ with b}\leq n, \\
          0, \quad &\text{otherwise.}  \\
     \end{cases}$

For (a), I tried to take limits of $f_n$ piecewise. In the first interval, limits of $f_n(x)=+\infty$. In the second one, I'm not sure whether limits of $f_n(x)=-\infty$. Since I graphed several $f_n$ on the second interval, their function value are always positive. But if I simply calculate $n-n^2x$ as $n\to\infty$, it would be $-\infty$. Besides, I'm also stuck on how to get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n$ and $\int_{0}^{1}f$ . If it's infinity, can I get  its integral on piecewise interval?

For(b), I think $f_n(x)$ is always jumping back and forth between 1 and 0, so its integral would be zero and the limit of its integral would be 1 on rational numbers and 0 on irrational numbers. But I'm not sure about $f(x)$ here, and get stuck again on how to get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n$ and $\int_{0}^{1}f$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a): For any $x>0$ the sequence $(f_n(x))$ is $0$ after some stage: $f_n(x)=0$ if $x > \frac 1 n$ or $n >\frac  1x$. Hence the limit of this sequence is $0$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. (Note that $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$). I will let you compute the integral of $f_n$ to see that $\int f_n$ does not tend to $0=\int f$.

(b): For any rational number $x=\frac p q$ we have $f_n(x)=1$ whenever $ n >q $ so $f(x)=\lim f_n(x)=1$. For $x$ irrational  $f(x)=\lim f_n(x)=0$. $\int f(x) dx$ does not exist as  a Riemann integral but its Lebesgue integral is $0$.

$\int f_n(x)dx=0$ for all $n$: If $x=\frac a b$ is a rational number(where $a$ and $b$ are integers) with $b \leq n$ and $0 \leq x\leq 1$ then there are only $n$ possible values for $b$ and only $b+1$ values of $a$ for  a given $b$. Hence $f_n(x)=0$ except for  a finite number of points $x$.

Comment: For（a）I computed the integral of $f_n$. Is it a non-zero constant?

Comment: @Kylinny Yes, that is correct.

Comment: For (b), I haven't learnt difference between Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral. Could you explain more about this one? Thanks very much.

Comment: By computing the upper and lower Riemann sums you can easily see that the function which is $1$ on rationals and $0$ on irrationals is not Riemann integrable. However $f=0$ almost everywher implies that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable with integral $0$. @Kylinny

Comment: I'm still a little confused about (b), does $\int{f_n}$ exist? Would this integral be 0?

Comment: @Kylinny For fixed $n$ the function is $0$ at all but a finite number of points .Such a function has Riemann integral $0$.

Comment: Why is this function 0 at all finite number of points when n is fixed? Isn't it jumping between 1 and 0?

Comment: @Kylinny How many rational numbers $\frac a b$ are there with $b \leq n$ and $0 \leq \frac a b \leq 1$?

Comment: I think there are infinitely many....@Kavi Rama Murthy